# update only leaves of a json file from another file

Tags: python, json

I have a Json file(dataSchema) and I want to fill the leaves with the values of another Json file(data).
Below an example of the two input files and what I want as output.

dataSchema:

```
"data": {
    "keyA": {},
    "keyB": {
        "keyB1" : {
             "keyB11" : ""
         }
     },
    "keyC": {},
    "keyD": {},
    "keyE": {
        "keyE1" : ""
    }
}
```

data:

```
"data": {
    "keyA": {
        "keyA1" : {
             "keyA11" : ValueA11,
             "keyA12" : ValueA12
         },
    },
    "keyB": {
        "keyB1" : {
             "keyB11" : ValueB11
         },
        "keyB2" : {
             "keyB21" : ValueB21
         },
        "keyB3" : {
             "keyB31" : ValueB31,
             "keyB32" : ValueB32
         }
     },
    "keyC": {
        "keyC1" : ValueC1
    },
    "keyD": {
        "keyD1" : {
             "keyD11" : ValueD11
         },
        "keyD2" : {
             "keyD21" : ValueD21
         }        
    },
    "keyE": {
        "keyE1" : {
             "keyE11" : {
                 "keyE111" : ValueE111,
                 "keyE112" : ValueE112
             },
             "keyE12" : ValueE12
         },
        "keyE2" : ValueE2
    }
}
```

What I want:

```
"data": {
    "keyA": {
        "keyA1" : {
             "keyA11" : ValueA11,
             "keyA12" : ValueA12
         },
    },
    "keyB": {
        "keyB1" : {
             "keyB11" : ValueB11
         }
     },
    "keyC": {
        "keyC1" : ValueC1
    },
    "keyD": {
        "keyD1" : {
             "keyD11" : ValueD11
         },
        "keyD2" : {
             "keyD21" : ValueD21
         }        
    },
    "keyE": {
        "keyE1" : {
             "keyE11" : {
                 "keyE111" : ValueE111,
                 "keyE112" : ValueE112
             },
             "keyE12" : ValueE12
         }
    }
}
```

I tried with update function but it includes all sub-keys.

There's a way to do this in elengant and short way with python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion for that:

```
def is_leaf(v):
    return v == {} or not isinstance(v, dict)


def fill_leaves(schema, data):
    return {k: v if is_leaf(schema[k]) else fill_leaves(schema[k], data[k]) for k, v in data.items() if k in schema}
```

Here is the same function with loop instad of dict comprehension (more readable):

```
def fill_leaves(schema, data):
    d_out = {}
    for k, v in data.items():
        if k in schema:
            if is_leaf(schema[k]):
                d_out[k] = v
            else:
                d_out[k] = fill_leaves(schema[k], data[k])
    return d_out
```

Answer (score 0):

well, let's do a recursive walk on schema tree:

```
def normalize(schema, data, result):
    for k in schema:
        value = schema[k]
        result[k] = value
        if not value or not isinstance(value, dict):
            # leaf
            if k in data:
                result[k] = data[k]
        elif k in data:
            normalize(schema[k], data[k], result[k])


rs = {}
normalize(schema, data, rs)
print json.dumps(rs, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
```